# ios 5 setPropertiesToFetch ...is not in the GROUP BY issue

Tags: core-data, ios5, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i'm using nsexpression to group and count on multiple attributes. the fetch result works fine under ios 6 and ios 7, but it doesnt work under ios 5.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions (startDateTime is not in the GROUP BY)'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x3689022 0x309bcd6 0x13357d9 0x133543e 0x13351f0 0x1334fc3 0x1334619 0x13340b0 0x133345d 0x13312fd 0x138432b 0x13841fc 0x1384051 0x3285951 0x3285e00 0x1383ff5 0x1383e6d 0x13312fd 0x144043f 0x3a55f 0x38fea 0x22c5a1e 0x2430323 0x3a796 0xc961 0x1b01c6 0xc572 0xc42a 0x1b0684 0x215b34 0x19dff2 0x215a8d 0x1b05cd 0xc142 0xf5c5 0x1b0684 0x215b34 0x19dff2 0x215a8d 0x1b05cd 0xd722 0x384b 0x21fc386 0x21fd274 0x220c183 0x220cc38 0x2200634 0x5177ef5 0x365d195 0x35c1ff2 0x35c08da 0x35bfd84 0x35bfc9b 0x21fcc65 0x21fe626 0x29ad 0x2915 0x1)
>   terminate called throwing an exception

and the code is as follow:

```
NSPropertyDescription *propDesc = [properties objectForKey:@"partyId"];
NSExpression *partyid           = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"partyId"];
NSExpression *partyIdCount      = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:partyid]];

NSExpressionDescription *countPartyId = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[countPartyId setExpression:partyIdCount];
[countPartyId setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];
[countPartyId setName:@"countResultPartyId"];

NSExpression *startDateTime = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"startDateTime"];
NSExpression *latestDateTime = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:startDateTime]];
NSExpressionDescription *dateTimePropertyDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[callDateTimePropertyDescription setExpression:latestDateTime];
[callDateTimePropertyDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];
[callDateTimePropertyDescription setName:@"latestDateTime"];

NSPropertyDescription *sortDateGroup = [properties objectForKey:@"sortDate"];
NSPropertyDescription *userId = [properties objectForKey:@"userId"];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:propDesc,sortDateGroup,userId, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:propDesc,dateTimePropertyDescription, sortDateGroup,userId,countPartyId, nil]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

it looks like it wants me to groupy by time `startDateTime` too. but grouping wont work because there could be multiple startDateTime and i need the latest "max" time from it. surprisingly, it works under ios 6 & 7- does anyobe know how to accomplish that? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `expressionForFunction:@"max:"` or `expressionForFunction:@"min:"` doenst work on ios 5. i had to leave it out of the query. and did a second query to get max nsdate for ios 5.